# Java Jsoup extracting <td> tags

Tags: html, jsoup

I need to collect all languages into my collection from this site.
Maybe someone knows how can I extract all of them without the column "ISO-639 code"?

[image]

I am using Jsoup for extracting HTML Tags. As far as I understand, in each  tag, I need to receive the first  tag. But I don't know how to get it.
[image]

Such code will return all  elements (including ISO-639 code):

```java
Elements elementObj = doc.select( "table" )
    .select( "tbody" )
    .select( "tr" )
    .select( "td" );
```

Answer (score 1):

First, get all `tr`'s. Then iterate and get first `td` for each row:

```java
Elements rows = doc.select("table").select("tbody").select("tr");
List<String> languageList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Element row : rows) {
    Element firstTd = row.selectFirst("td");
    languageList.add(firstTd.text());
}
System.out.println(languageList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Krystian's answer, here's a one-liner version using the `nth-child` selector to retrieve the first column, and the [`eachText()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#eachText()) method that compiles the textnode value of each selected element into a list. Just some syntactic sugar to make your code a bit simpler.

```java
String html = """
    <table>
    <tr><th>Language</th><th>ISO Code</th>
    <tr><td>Afrikaans</td><td>af</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Albanian</td><td>sq</td></tr>
    </table>
    """;

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
List<String> languages = doc.select("tr td:nth-child(1)").eachText();

print(languages.toString());
```

Gives:

```
[Afrikaans, Albanian]
```

[Try jsoup](https://try.jsoup.org/%7Er74evtjoMKx_dA2WX7tuIplt8ko) is a good way to play around with different selectors.